Battery indicator circuit
I have seen designs for a battery level indicator for 0, 25, 50, 75 and 0, 20, 40, 60, 80. They all pretty much use a voltage divider. But there are times when you want to know if a battery is at 5% in which maybe an lcd/oled will warn of low battery voltage, then a 3% status saying that battery needs to be recharged (built-in charger within pcb). Also it displays the battery percentage depending on the formula: \$\frac{V_{battTotal}}{V_{current}}\$. I am wondering if using 100 resistors (lowest voltage (excluding 0v) in an n-resistor voltage divider is \$\frac{V_{batt}}{n}\$) in series can achieve this. Or is there another way of doing this just by using simple ICs?
Edit:
I have a voltage battery selector that I know how to make using logic gates (user can push individual switch depending on voltage: 12V is 1100 which can be read by the microcontroller). Microcontroller can be an arduino uno/mega.

some microcontrollers are just simple ICs ... use one of them

determining the remaining charge is more complicated than just measuring voltage ... besides Vcurrent/Vtotal would only work if a depleted battery would  be at 0 V

You can use a 8bit ADC chip that gives you 256 steps of battery level instead of using 100 resistors.

then i use an analog pin to do current sensing

how do i use adc for arduino

@JadonJung analogRead();

A real "battery indicator" is essentially a battery "charger"/"discharger" device. You need measure and integrate ... voltage AND current circulating in the battery.

You need to know the cell chemistry to determine the state of charge from voltage.
For example, in the diagram below, from Battery Power Tips,

a lead-acid cell has a fairly linear cell voltage to charge curve. At full charge, each cell would be at ~2.4 V, at half capacity, ~2 V, and it is effectively discharged at ~1.8 V. It's easy to calculate remaining charge based on voltage.
For the two lithium chemistries, note that there is hardly any voltage drop between 90% charge and 20% charge. Trying to calculate the state of charge from voltage alone is difficult, as even a slight current drawn during measurement might make the cell appear to have far less charge left.
Accurate indication requires measuring cell voltage under a pulsed load, and interpretation through a lookup table or equation using a microcontroller.
